# Getting a string in a list to be equal a dataframe in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shortcut

I have a list of strings containing table_names:

```
table = ['table A', 'table B', 'table C'.... 'table J']
```

I also have a list of dataframes:

```
list_of_dataframes = [df1, df2, df3 ..]
```

These lists are of equal length.

How do I loop through both dataframes and get them equal to each other?

I manage to loop them individually as follows but would like them to be equal to each other such that `df1 = table A`.. `df10 = table J`.

For loop I tried

```
for i in table:
     i = l
for l in list_of_dataframes:
     l = i
```

Comment: First, `table A` is not a valid identifier in Python. Second, why do you want separate variables for each dataframe? Why not use a `dict` to store references to dataframes by table name, e.g. `{"table A": df1, "table B": df2, ...}`?

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working about your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a dictionary for this?

You can do something like:

```
for i, item in enumerate(table):
    table_name = item.split()[1]
    dict_of_tables[table_name] = list_of_dataframes[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is a much more appropriate way to store these dataframes:

```py
>>> dict(zip(table, list_of_dataframes))
# {"table A": df1, "table B": df2, ...}
```

Or, if you want to refer to them simply by their letter:

```py
>>> dict(zip("".join(table).replace("table ", ""), list_of_dataframes))
# {"A": df1, "B": df2, ...}
```